# Learn about reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, optimization

Why are reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces an important topic to learn? What is possibly achievable with that theory that is not reachable with just standard Hilbert space theory?

Comment: well, where did you come across them? one big application is in the theory of wavelets - a hardly insignificant field of study.

Comment: @icurays1 I came across them while reading about spherical splines. It looked to me that too much time was spent on the machinery construction with little to show at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I learned about them is they're essential in machine learning, for getting an SVM classifier to work.